# MySQL - importing 88000 rows from a csv file inserts only 39 rows

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

I am trying to import a csv file containing +88000 entries into a table xyz I created using the following query:

```
LOAD DATA LOW_PRIORITY LOCAL INFILE 
'C:\\Users\\Simo\\Desktop\\file.csv' IGNORE INTO TABLE
`complete`.`xyz` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY 'auto' 
(`datetime`, `city`, `state`, `country`, `shape`, `duration (seconds)`, `duration (hours/min)`, `comments`, `date posted`, `latitude`, `longitude`)
```

Only 39 rows are inserted as this is the output I get :

```
Query OK, 39 rows affected, 149 warnings (0.23 sec)
Records: 39  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 149
```

The Warnings:

```
Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'longitude' at row 1                                                                                                                                               |
| Warning | 1262 | Row 1 was truncated; it contained more data than there were input columns                                                                                                                    |
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'country' at row 2                                                                                                                                                 |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect decimal value: '"White lights race through the sky in clear daylight&#44 fighters in persuit"' for column 'longitude' at row 2                                                     |
| Warning | 1262 | Row 2 was truncated; it contained more data than there were input columns                                                                                                                    |
| Warning | 1261 | Row 3 doesn't contain data for all columns                                                                                                                                                   |
| Warning | 1261 | Row 3 doesn't contain data for all columns                                                                                                                                                   |
| Warning | 1261 | Row 3 doesn't contain data for all columns                                                                                                                                                   |
| Warning | 1261 | Row 3 doesn't contain data for all columns                                                                                                                                                   |
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'country' at row 4                                                                                                                                                 |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect decimal value: '"Bright orb and strange craft flying over Vancouver&#44 Wa"' for column 'longitude' at row 4                                                                       |
| Warning | 1262 | Row 4 was truncated; it contained more data than there were input columns                                                                                                                    |
| Warning | 1261 | Row 5 doesn't contain data for all columns                                                                                                                                                   |
| Warning | 1261 | Row 5 doesn't contain data for all columns                                                                                                                                                   |
| Warning | 1261 | Row 5 doesn't contain data for all columns                                                                                                                                                   |
| Warning | 1261 | Row 5 doesn't contain data for all columns                                                                                                                                                   |
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'country' at row 6                                                                                                                                                 |
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'shape' at row 6                                                                                                                                                   |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect decimal value: '"North Kansas City UFO"' for column 'longitude' at row 6                                                                                                           |
| Warning | 1262 | Row 6 was truncated; it contained more data than there were input columns                                                                                                                    |
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'duration (hours/min)' at row 7                                                                                                                                    |
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'latitude' at row 7                                                                                                                                                |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect decimal value: 'lisbon' for column 'longitude' at row 7                                                                                                                            |
| Warning | 1262 | Row 7 was truncated; it contained more data than there were input columns                                                                                                                    |
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'country' at row 8                                                                                                                                                 |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect decimal value: '"ufos playing in the night sky near the southern cross star cluster"' for column 'longitude' at row 8                                                              |
| Warning | 1262 | Row 8 was truncated; it contained more data than there were input columns                                                                                                                    |
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'datetime' at row 9                                                                                                                                                |
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'country' at row 9                                                                                                                                                 |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect decimal value: '"Two craft 3 miles from each other close to the ground seen by two in Central Washington November 1999"' for column 'longitude' at row 9                           |
| Warning | 1262 | Row 9 was truncated; it contained more data than there were input columns                                                                                                                    |
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'duration (hours/min)' at row 10                                                                                                                                   |
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'latitude' at row 10                                                                                                                                               |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect decimal value: 'rockwall' for column 'longitude' at row 10                                                                                                                         |
| Warning | 1262 | Row 10 was truncated; it contained more data than there were input columns                                                                                                                   |
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'datetime' at row 11                                                                                                                                               |
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'country' at row 11                                                                                                                                                |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect decimal value: '"Shiny golden metallic sphere gliding across the skies of Atlanta&#44 GA. December 15&#44 1998&#44 09:07am."' for column 'longitude' at row 11                     |
| Warning | 1262 | Row 11 was truncated; it contained more data than there were input columns                                                                                                                   |
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'duration (hours/min)' at row 12                                                                                                                                   |
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'latitude' at row 12                                                                                                                                               |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect decimal value: 'seaford' for column 'longitude' at row 12                                                                                                                          |
| Warning | 1262 | Row 12 was truncated; it contained more data than there were input columns                                                                                                                   |
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'country' at row 13                                                                                                                                                |
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'shape' at row 13                                                                                                                                                  |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect decimal value: '"I am a graduate student at Western Kentucky University in Bowling Green.  I was on my way to an evening class.  I exited Cumber' for column 'longitude' at row 13 |
| Warning | 1262 | Row 13 was truncated; it contained more data than there were input columns                                                                                                                   |
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'datetime' at row 14                                                                                                                                               |
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'country' at row 14                                                                                                                                                |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect decimal value: '"I was driving north on HWY 101 over the hill from Peteluma to Cotati when I saw a green/blue orb pass in front of my car in the' for column 'longitude' at row 14 |
| Warning | 1262 | Row 14 was truncated; it contained more data than there were input columns                                                                                                                   |
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'country' at row 15                                                                                                                                                |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect decimal value: '"Floating bell shaped object with pure white lights tinged with silver angel or ufo?"' for column 'longitude' at row 15                                            |
| Warning | 1262 | Row 15 was truncated; it contained more data than there were input columns                                                                                                                   |
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'country' at row 16                                                                                                                                                |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect decimal value: '"Red Orbs."' for column 'longitude' at row 16                                                                                                                      |
| Warning | 1262 | Row 16 was truncated; it contained more data than there were input columns                                                                                                                   |
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'country' at row 17                                                                                                                                                |
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'shape' at row 17                                                                                                                                                  |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect decimal value: '"MUFON member reports gigantic&#44 black ship passes NNE over house at 5 mph. 20 min sighting. Good rept."' for column 'longitude' at row 17                       |
| Warning | 1262 | Row 17 was truncated; it contained more data than there were input columns                                                                                                                   |
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'datetime' at row 18                                                                                                                                               |
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'country' at row 18                                                                                                                                                |
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'shape' at row 18                                                                                                                                                  |
```

I wonder why does it insert only 39 rows when the files contains more than 88000 rows of data ?

How do I make it continue inserting regardless of any warnings or errors ?

This is the csv file I am trying to import: [File](https://github.com/planetsig/ufo-reports/blob/master/csv-data/ufo-scrubbed-geocoded-time-standardized.csv)

Comment: Change `'auto'` to `'\n'` to use a line return, as well as add the "optionally enclosed by" found [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html)

Comment: it works!!! Please write an answer I will mark it as accepted. thanks a lot

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here: It's looking to end the line on the word 'auto' instead of a new line, and some (but only some) of the strings are enclosed in quotes. So you'll need to tweak the query like so:

```
LOAD DATA LOW_PRIORITY LOCAL INFILE 
    'C:\\Users\\Simo\\Desktop\\file.csv' IGNORE INTO TABLE
      `complete`.`xyz` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
      OPTIONALLY BY '"'
      LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
    (`datetime`, `city`, `state`, `country`, `shape`, `duration (seconds)`, `duration (hours/min)`, `comments`, `date posted`, `latitude`, `longitude`)
```

Comment: You are a legend!

Answer (score 1):

You either need to have the correct data filled in for all columns for each row, OR, you need to edit your table structure to allow for the data set you have. IE, you need to allow for empty values and make sure the values entered match the data type of the column.

Answer (score 0):

The error shows that every row in CSV file does not match column structure. Some rows contains more number of columns and some contains less number of columns than in actual table structure.